# Rails Minitest: "false is not a symbol or a string" when using assert_predicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

In a rails unit test using [Minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest), with the following code:

```
def test_notification
  # ("Arrange" stuff here...)

  get root_path

  assert_predicate flash, blank?
end
```

When run, the `assert_predicate` line causes the error:

`Minitest::UnexpectedError: TypeError: false is not a symbol nor a string`

What's going on here?

Comment: Just googled this problem and the first result was this answer. Thanks, 2017 self!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `blank?` needs to be a symbol -- it's missing the leading `:` in the snippet above.  The corrected code:

```
def test_notification
  # ("Arrange" stuff here...)

  get root_path

  assert_predicate flash, :blank?
end
```